# NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object Oclusion.OnTriggerEnter2D (UnityEngine.Collider2D other)

Tags: c#

[image: ошибочка]помогите пожалуйста, возникла проблема и не могу решить[image: =как я понимаю ошибка вplatforma.SetActive(true);]

Comment: В чем проблема то?

Comment: Можно пожалуйста саму ошибку прикрепить?

Comment: По этому куску невозможно определить по какой причине не инициализируется переменная platforma. Судя по всему ошибка возникает в GetComponent и он возвращает ноль, позднее вы обращаетесь к этому объекту, разному нулю - это вызывает exception.

Comment: @newview Уже оставил ответ, у него не задана переменная в Инспекторе.

Comment: а как ее правильно задать ?

Comment: @shi fu заходите в инспектор и к переменной привязываете компонент

Comment: @shi fu Подробнее на сайте документации Unity: https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/current/Manual/VariablesAndTheInspector.html

Comment: большое спасибо)

Answer (score 1):

Исходя из Вашей ошибки можно понять, что переменная `platforma` записывает в себя значение `null`, а потом Вы пытаетесь к ней обратиться, но у Вас возвращает ошибку `NullReferenceException`, что означает попытку обращения к нулевому объекту. Проверьте, привязали ли Вы компонент к этой переменной в Инспекторе.